# sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type. Error: django.db.utils.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

When I try to save some Django model like for example this one:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    payment_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Undefined")
    total_no_of_products = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    total_paid = models.FloatField(default=0)
    ids = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), default=list)
    user = models.OneToOneField(NewUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    metadata = models.ManyToManyField(Metadata)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.user_name}"
```

inside Django shell with:

```
>>>profil1 = UserProfile(address="1111", payment_type="credit", total_no_of_products=10, total_paid=100, user=user1)
>>> profil1.save()
```

I get in return following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
    return super().execute(query, params)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 134, in debug_sql
        yield
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 122, in execute
        return super().execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
        return self._execute_with_wrappers(
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
        return executor(sql, params, many, context)
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in _execute
        with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
        raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 105, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 328, in execute
        return super().execute(query, params)
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 814, in save
        self.save_base(
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 901, in save_base
        updated = self._save_table(
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1059, in _save_table
        results = self._do_insert(
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1100, in _do_insert
        return manager._insert(
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1845, in _insert
        return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1822, in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 121, in execute
        with self.debug_sql(sql, params, use_last_executed_query=True):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 139, in debug_sql
        sql = self.db.ops.last_executed_query(self.cursor, sql, params)
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 176, in last_executed_query
        params = self._quote_params_for_last_executed_query(params)
      File "/home/ilija/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/django-db-IyYlsnQa-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 165, in _quote_params_for_last_executed_query
        return cursor.execute(sql, params).fetchone()
    sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 4 - probably unsupported type.
```

I try to figure out what cause this problem and I found that when I comment out this line

```
ids = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), default=list)
```

problem disappear. Does anybody have idea why is this?

Currently I'm using Django 5.0 with default sqlite3 db.

Tnx!

Comment: _When I try to save some Django model_ Show us the full code that saves the model.  Don't make us guess what you did.

Comment: Also post the full error traceback.

Comment: `ArrayField` is clearly [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/)  as being specific to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing sqllit3.db for Postgres.

Reason for issue is basically ArrayField. Sqllite3 can not properly handle this field. I didn't dig deeper to figure out why.

Basically this line from my model caused all havoc:

`ids = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True), default=list)`

And moving from sqlite to Posgres resolved whole issue.

Comment: 1) What you have found out is you need to develop against the database you plan to run in production 2) It pays to read the docs [SQLite typing](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html). Pay particular attention to section *3. Type Affinity*. It does not apply to this case, but it is the big issue when moving from SQLite to another database.